Do I need to have a privacy policy or something for my virtual assistant service?
I am wanting to offer virtual assistance as a service with my business. Since I might be dealing with people's emails and personal info, do I need some document/contract to make sure that the client's data is staying private? If so, what kind of document, and where can I get it?

im no legal judge or anything. but my mum went to legal school for a little while and I know it depends. if your virtual assistant collects or uses any form of data I belive you do need a privacy policy. as it tells people what type of data you collect. and how you use it. but this is easy to make as there is plenty of bases and I just use the google docs one, and if you put a clause(I think its called) in your TOS that says by using the assistant and website you agree then yes. usually there's a tick box where you have them agree and then it sends it to a server saying you do agree, here's a base privacy policy from google

You very clearly do need a privacy policy, though the details will depend on what jurisdiction you're operating in.
That means you need to consult specialist lawyers.
Who could define or explain 'virtual' as opposed to 'real' assistance changes what?
What jurisdiction you're operating 'in' is vital; more when the services are 'virtual'.
Clearly, you offer your services from within your local jurisdiction and your clients accept and pay for those services from within their local jurisdictions but then what?
Was the contract made or concluded in your or your client's or, since you brought up the idea, some virtual space?
Every detail might be open to endless legal debate and still, you very clearly do need a privacy policy.

It's not a requirement but it's in your best interest.
A privacy policy will let the user know how their data will be managed and an EULA (End User License Agreement) will set boundaries for what essentially you can be sued for.
Privacy policy and EULAs are essentially lawyer speak for "you agree to give me all your data so I can use it for whatever I want" and "you won't sue me for anything if this service causes you problems"
Example:
Let's say, for example, your virtual assistance insults your client or outputs wrong information that causes your client to lose money.
With an EULA, you can vaguely say that all messages from the assistant should be double checked and it's the user's responsibility to do so, and the user also agrees that any problems caused by the use of the software are the user's fault.
Without an EULA, the client could sue you for damages, since using your software caused them to lose money.
So, yes. Get an EULA, get a privacy policy and if you're operating in europe, get a GDPR policy too.
There are free EULA generators online, you could use one of those for now and get an actual lawyer to tailor one specifically for you business later when you're making money from it.
This isn't legal advice and you can't hold me responsible for anything. (See how this works?)
